# How do I override / encapsulate the backbone 'set' method

Tags: backbone.js

If I wish to strip out some extra spaces, and ensure http:// is prepended to any input whenever a call like so is made

```
    myModel.set('url','www.google.com');
```

Comment: Might be better to define a setURL method that does the prepending and then delegates to set. Changing the behaviour of set, even if it's only for MyModel, seems like a bad idea because you would have to make the behaviour conditional on the key you're trying to set.

Comment: @rjsvaljean, +1 for pointing out that what I'm trying to do may not be a good idea :-), also looks like a solid solution to the actual question is more effort than it's worth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agree with @rjsvaljean, but if you really want to override set method for myModel then do it like that:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    set: function(attributes, options) {    
        // 'strip out some extra spaces, and ensure http is prepended' here

        return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attributes, options);
    }
});
```

Comment: But `set` can be called as `m.set('a', 'b')` or `m.set({a: 'b'})` so you have to unpack the arguments to `set` manually before you clean things up and chain to the base class.

Comment: Also as @rjsvaljean points out we'd need a condition to check that the key is 'url'